How to use kexec on Guix? Getting a blank screen
I'm trying to use kexec on Guix, which I think should be
kexec -l /run/current-system/kernel/bzImage  --append="$(cat /proc/cmdline)" --initrd=/run/current-system/initrd
kexec -e

However, that results in a blank screen. I can still reboot through alt-printscreen-b, so the (old or new) kernel is still running. The other alt-printscreen-reisub letters don't seem to do anything (not even fans spinning up).
As for the XY-problem, I'd like to be able to skip grub. Mainly because the drive is encrypted, and I have to enter the LUKS password twice: for grub and for the kernel. So I hope to save some time by booting directly into Linux and having to decrypt the drive only once.
Not sure whether this is actually a Guix problem, or something else.
